# 404 error with IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have a text file that I am trying to browse to using the browser `http://files.mydomain.com/test.txt` and I get a:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not found
```

I double checked and the text file does exist. When I add a `test.htm` file, I have no issues.

Can someone help? Something tells me it's security issue.

Comment: What turned out to be the problem?

Comment: It was the mime type issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the following:

1. Your DNS 'A' record for 'files' is pointing to the correct IP address
2. If your server is using a shared IP address across multiple sites have you configured a HTTP host header?
3. Is there a mime type set for the `.txt` extension?
4. Have you made any changes to the Handler Mappings for the site? e.g. mapped the `.htm` extension to say the ASP ISAPI filter and accidentally removed the StaticFile handler?
5. Can you serve other static content such as `.jpg`, `.gif`, `.pdf` etc?

Answer (score 2):

Kev has covered most of the possible problems, but for reference there is another possibility.

Confirm that in `Request Filtering` you either

- have `.txt` as an Allowed extension, or
- have `Allow unlisted file name extensions` ticked in *Edit Request Filtering Settings*

The same effect can be achieved with the following web.config section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <fileExtensions>
                <add fileExtension=".txt" allowed="true" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure also that the website is started. I was getting 404 and then realized that the Default Website was stopped because another website (Sharepoint) was using port 80. Sometimes the obvious is what gets you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the MIME-Typ by going to ...

1. features / Mime-type
2. right click,
3. add,
4. put in the file extension ".txt"
5. and the mime-type "text/plain"
6. ok

et voila

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but this might still help somebody out. I ran into this problem with my Asp.Net Core application. In my case it turned out that static files are served from a subdirectory called 'wwwroot' by default. Creating that subdirectory and moving the file in their solved it for me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows#web-root